# Calling one python script from another python script and wait unit execution completes

Tags: python, python-3.3

Let me explain my problem with an example:

I have script1.py, which is like:

script1.py

```
for (i in range(0,10))
    generate script2.py
    execute(script3.py)
```

`script3.py` imports `script2.py`.

What I need to do is generate different script2.py for 10 times and then execute script3.py. script3.py generates a folder, copying all files from the same folder where all three scripts resides, to a different location. There are some parameters defined in script2.py, which are used by script3.py to generate a folder name, and then copies all files to that folder.

I have tried using `os.system()`, `subprocess.call` with `wait`, `subprocess.Popen` with communication, but I am not being able to do it correctly.

What happens is, even though the iteration count is 10, it does not generates 10 folders. Although parameters are being changed in script2.py, script3.py is using old parameters to generate folder name.

I am doing this on a Windows machine, using Python 3.3.

Any pointers to possible solution or any mistake I might be doing?

Comment: You're saying `this should create more folders than it does`, but you aren't showing us any code that creates folders. We aren't psychic. Given this limited information, all we can say is: There are bugs in your code.

Comment: Sorry for the vague question. I have updated the question. I hope this is more clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Use `subprocess`. Example below.

```
import subprocess

for i in range(10):
    generate script2.py

    cmd = ['python', 'script3.py']
    subprocess.Popen(cmd).wait()

    # Python will now wait for script3 to return
    # before going on to the next iteration
```

**[Useful documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html)**

Comment: On Windows, I need to add the command "python" as well I guess.

Comment: On windows, I will have to add "python" also in the command I guess.
I tried this, but, it is generating less number of folders then it should.

I am not sure why the wait command is not working properly.

Comment: If it generates 7 folders when asked for 10, try to ask for 15 and it may generate 10 :)

Comment: Just saw your edit in your answer.
I am not executing both script2 and script3.

I am generating a file "script2.py" in the script1.py and then executing script3.py only, which imports scrtip2.py.

Comment: but don't know the answer - quite weird

Comment: haha.. that is unfortunately not an option.. as I need to generate precisely 10 script2.py and corresponding 10 folders for each file. :P

Comment: use a debugger and place a breakpoint in your loop, and see what happens